# AngularJS and returning object in javascript array via function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having troubles trying to return an object within an array in an if-else loop within a function.

Basically, I want to return the first item object in the array and the getItemDetails will run and get the first item and then if triggered again, it will clear the array and write the other item object to it.

I have a service called ItemService that contains the following function:

```
  getItemDetails: function(details) {

      if (itemDetails.length == 0) {


        itemDetails.push(details);


        return itemDetails;

        console.log(itemDetails[0].name);
      }
      else {

        itemDetails = [];

        itemDetails.push(details);

        console.log (itemDetails[0].name);

        return itemDetails;

        console.log(itemDetails[0].name);

      }
```

This is the controller:

```
.controller("itemListingDetailCtrl", function ($scope, itemService, $stateParams, $state)
{

  $scope.name = itemService.getItemDetails()[0].name;
  $scope.description = itemService.getItemDetails()[0].desc;

})
```

Here is the accordion that contains the onSelectItems function that takes a JSON object as a parameter.

```
<ion-item class="item-accordion"
                        ng-repeat="item_type in item.subcategories"
                        ng-show="isGroupShown(beer)"
                        ng-click="onSelectItems(item_type)">
                  {{item_type.name}}
             </ion-item>
```

Whenever it runs, I can see in the console logs that I receive the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.getItemDetails
```

If I remove the if else loop and simply push the item to the array and return itemDetails, it will give me the correct first item in the array. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is 'details' in itemService.getItemDetails()[0].name; because definition of service function is looking for the 'details' as in   getItemDetails: function(details) {}

Answer (score 1):

First important thing is that **if-else** is not a loop, but a conditional statement, loop examples are **while** and **for**. You can read more about [control flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling) and [loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) in JS on MDN.

The error which you're getting is because you expect `details` to be always defined when passed as an argument to `getItemDetails`.  You're accessing its `name` property in this line: `console.log (itemDetails[0].name);`. But in the controller code you're calling `itemService.getItemDetails()` without any argument, so `details` is `undefined` and a `TypeError` is thrown.

If you want this to work you should pass a valid object to the `getItemDetails`. Still please think a bit about the design, the role of `getItemDetails` is unclear to me. You're just wrapping the `details` object into an `Array`, you don't really need a service to do this.

Additionally in the `getItemDetails` function you have unreachable code. The `console.log` immediately after `return` statements won't be executed. You should remove it.

Comment: I agree, a service is usually used to persist and share data bewteeen controllers. Also it is common to keep business logic inside controllers and data logic inside services.